# When to add something to the redux store versus the component specific store when using React Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am currently updating a React project without Redux to one with Redux. As you would expect each component has its own State and is passed Props. In the process of implementing Redux I am able to get rid of all of the passing of Props down to child components. However, I am a bit confused with what I should be doing with component State items that are meant just for that component. I believe I should be leaving them as is, and not add them to Redux.

For example, two component specific state properties that I think should probably be left as is are the following:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        message: null,
        redirect: null
    };
```

These properties are just used to specify where to redirect the user to or what message to show when a form is submitted.

If someone can help me understand when I should be adding something to the Redux Store versus just keeping it as part of the component store that would be great. I also want to make sure I will still have access to use Props the normal way in some scenarios if I wanted to. It looks like all React-Redux does it map everything to Props anyway so it would just add things to the original Props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using local state is fine**. Usually one of the hardest questions in React is where to put state. And it is you as a developer should decide whether or not use state locally or not.
You need to use redux when:

- this data will be used in different parts of application
- you need to cache this data (to be able to restore it from state and not performing another network request for example)
- you want to keep this data consistent while hot-reloading UI components
- you need time travel debugging

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you don't know if you need to use redux, then you don't need redux.

We use a lot of redux, and made a "[best practice](https://mapado.github.io/best-practices/docs/en/redux#when-to-use-redux)" on it, but we now rely on Dan Abramov's post: [You might not need redux](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367).

You don't have to "reduxify" your app, redux, is only here to share global state between several component, but local state is fine. Finally, React added the [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) and the [useReducer hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) that can solve the same problems that redux solves whith a more "local" approach.